# android app crashed because of xml

Tags: android, xml, button

What I do wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/element1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/kolo_1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/element2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/trojkat_1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/element3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/kwadrat_1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/element4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wielokat_1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/element5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gwiazdka_1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/element6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/romb_1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonstart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="@string/play"
    android:textColor="#efefef"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/kolo_1"
        android:onClick="button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/trojkat_1"
        android:onClick="button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/kwadrat_1"
        android:onClick="button3" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/wielokat_1"
        android:onClick="button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/gwiazdka_1"
        android:onClick="button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/romb_1"
        android:onClick="button6" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
06-07 15:55:25.669: D/libEGL(1642): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-07 15:55:25.679: D/libEGL(1642): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-07 15:55:25.689: D/libEGL(1642): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-07 15:55:25.689: D/libEGL(1642): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-07 15:55:25.759: D/OpenGLRenderer(1642): Enabling debug mode 0
06-07 15:55:31.349: D/AndroidRuntime(1642): Shutting down VM
06-07 15:55:31.349: W/dalvikvm(1642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4a1f8)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arsoft.shootandremember/com.arsoft.shootandremember.Remember}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at com.arsoft.shootandremember.Remember.onCreate(Remember.java:79)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-07 15:55:31.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     ... 11 more
06-07 15:55:32.649: I/Process(1642): Sending signal. PID: 1642 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
```

Wild guess: you declared an **ImageButton** and then try to assign it to a **Button** in your onCreate method.
You don't have **ImageButtons** in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to clean your project and then run. and also tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass} this line not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

your logcat says that you are doing wrong typecasting.you are trying to cast a button into imagebutton:

## Wrong:

```
Button _button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
```

## Correct:

```
Button _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
```

Comment: Also wrong: `ImageButton _imgbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);` when you are pointing a button (R.id.yourbuttonid in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to turn one of your (Button)'s into an (ImageButton) in your OnCreate method.

1. Change the (Button) to an (ImageButton) in your xml or...
2. Cast the (Button) to a regular (Button) in your OnCreate method

Hope this helps